# How to locate ::before element in Selenium and get its contents?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, pseudo-element

[screenshot.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYAzZ.png)

Hi All,

I am having a situation where a ::before in HTML code is pointing to asterisk (mandatory field) in HTML page. Please see attached screenshot.

**HTML code:**

```
<lightning-input-field class="customRequired abc">
::before
    <lightning-picklist>
    </lightning-picklist>
</lightning-input-field>
```

How to write xpath for ::before?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no straight forward solution instead use javascript :

> querySelector takes css selectors

```
css_selector = 'lightning-input-field[class="customerRequired"]'
browser.execute_script("return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('{}'),':before').getPropertyValue('content')".format(css_selector))
```

Comment: It is throwing exception: unknown error: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

Comment: @SurenderDargan add the url then , and don't forget to check the selector I added .

Comment: @SurenderDargan this is the python way you just redefine it in java syntax .